# Select distinct one column by conditions from the other 2 columns (how to pair them?)

Tags: mysql

I need to get the id_user by values given in other columns. My table look like this:

```
id(AI,PK)       id_user     attr_name   attr_value  
----------------------------------------------------
1               1           hair        brown
2               1           eyes        green
3               2           hair        blond
4               1           age         40
5               1           sex         male
6               2           eyes        green
7               2           age         40
8               2           sex         male
```

When I try a query like this:

---

```
select distinct id_user where (attr_name='hair' and attr_value='blond') or (attr_name='eyes' and attr_value='green')
```

---

I will obviously get id_user=1 and 2, because both of them have green eyes.

If I change "or" to "and" it seems that the query does not work at all. But I need "and" because 2 (or even more, I shortened my example) conditions must be met, to get the specified id_user:

```
select distinct id_user where (attr_name='hair' and attr_value='blond') and (attr_name='eyes' and attr_value='green')
```

How to "pair" those 2 brackets, so I will get only a user where both conditions met: green eyes and blond hair?

Comment: Don't you need `FROM` clause?

Comment: Yes originally I had FROM, just missed it in while re-typing the query (I was typing 
 new query because this is not a  "users" base, I had my reasons to hide original subject:). However Mihai wrote a solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use post aggregate filtering with HAVING.

WHERE filters rows, HAVING with aggregate functions filters groups.

```
SELECT id_user FROM t 
GROUP BY id_user 
HAVING SUM(attr_name='hair')>0 AND SUM( attr_value='blond') >0
  AND SUM(attr_name='eyes')>0 AND SUM( attr_value='green') >0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is.

```
SELECT `u1`.`id_user`,
IF(`u1`.`attr_name` RLIKE 'hair' AND `u1`.`attr_value` = 'blond',1,0) AS `blond`,
IF(`u2`.`attr_name` RLIKE 'eyes' AND `u2`.`attr_value` = 'green',1,0) AS `green` 
FROM `users` `u1` 
INNER JOIN `users` `u2`
ON `u1`.`id_user`=`u2`.`id_user`
HAVING `green`+`blond` = 2;
```

OR

```
SELECT `u1`.`id_user`
FROM `users` `u1` 
INNER JOIN `users` `u2`
ON `u1`.`id_user`=`u2`.`id_user`
WHERE IF(`u1`.`attr_name` RLIKE 'hair' AND `u1`.`attr_value` = 'blond',1,0) + IF(`u2`.`attr_name` RLIKE 'eyes' AND `u2`.`attr_value` = 'green',1,0) = 2;
```

The result is

```
id_user blond   green
   2      1       1
```

To re-create the example use:

```
create table `users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `id_user` INT,
  `attr_name`  VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `attr_value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)  ENGINE=INNODB;

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`,`id_user`,`attr_name`,`attr_value`) VALUES (1,1,'hair','blond'),(2,1,'eyes','blue'),(3,2,'hair','blond'),(4,2,'eyes','green'),(5,2,'sex','male'),(6,2,'age','42'),(7,1,'sex','female'),(8,1,'age','39');
```

Try it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5f04fb/17)

Comment: it works, but it is more complicated query and usualy joins are more demanding processes for the database (in this particular example: 7ms vs 5ms of Mihai's solution). I am working up to 20 conditions and it should search through 10mln records, execution time is crucial. Hovewer +1 for your idea and participation :) Thanks.

Comment: @Trueman indeed joins are a bit more costly as written this is just another approach. You can of course optimize it a bit by making `id_user` `INDEX`.